# Possible to use a parameter as an animate property name?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-animate

I tried doing a search - maybe my terminology is off, but I can't find an answer. I'm trying to make a plugin where I can pass a css property name through a function. This is what I have, but it only works if I replace the param with the actual property name...

http://jsfiddle.net/2Cq6S/1/

```
(function($){
    $.fn.clickPlugin = function(param){
        $(this).animate({param:'100px'});
    };
}(jQuery));   


$('.click').click(function(){
    $(this).clickPlugin('height');
});

Any help would be awesome
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the `obj[name]` syntax to use a variable name for a property like this:

```
(function($){
    $.fn.clickPlugin = function(param){
        var obj = {};
        obj[param] = '100px';
        this.animate(obj);
    };
}(jQuery));
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/2q5m4/

To use the variable name, you have to assign it with code.  There is no way to use the variable name for a property in a static object declaration.  Thus, the code above creates the object then assigns the property with a line of JS.

---

FYI, in a jQuery plug-in method, `this` is already the host jQuery object so you don't have to wrap it in `$(this)` to use it as a jQuery object.